# Viewing a public Calendar in android

Tags: android, eclipse, view, import, calendar

I am creating an app and one of the options is that you will be able to open a public google calendar and view it on the phone.

The calendar is from a different users google account but it is public so everyone can view it.  I am new to android development and didn't know the best way to go about this.  What I would like to happen is somehow import the calendar or the calendar events and have them open on the devices google calendar.  But I don't want the events to actually sync to the users phone.  I only want them to be able to view them when they click the button of this part of the app.  If anyone can help me out that would be much appreciated.

I have looked into this question and can't seem to find anything.  I know there is a google Calendar view but i'm not sure if its helpful.

Thanks

Comment: which type of calender  u want open ,

Comment: Just a simple Google Calendar.

Comment: k have the the answer check it , if helpful upvote

Answer (score 0):

collin this two link may help you , means there are two class, make the project , and use acc to your requirement and modified acc. to you may it helps you http://pastie.org/private/eojz2vudd7dpgcm1niczg and http://pastie.org/private/sm4cruhdpx4oulcggreznw